# Can't launch any apps when Desktop set to show contents of ~/Desktop

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, 23.04

Yesterday I installed Kubuntu 23.04 (fresh install), set everything up, and everything was working fine, including after multiple restarts. This morning, the icons on my desktop were missing and I couldn't launch any apps. Only thing I could still launch was "Configure Desktop and Wallpaper" by right-clicking on the desktop, though the "Configure Display Settings" below didn't work.

Using `journalctl` (in recovery mode), I noticed a number of `kernel: __vm_enough_memory: pid: 1364, comm: plasmashell, no enough memory for the allocation` messages that seemed to match the timing. I don't know if they're related or not, but they seemed the most obvious candidates.

After much experimenting, it turns out the problem only occurs when I set the Desktop to show the contents of my Desktop folder (~/Desktop) under "Configure Desktop and Wallpaper" -> "Location". If I set it to show my Home folder, everything is well (after a restart).

In my ~/Desktop folder I have my Documents, Downloads, Pictures and Videos folders, as well as one other folder. Nothing else.

I thought maybe it had to do with folder previews, that maybe a preview of some file was causing trouble, but turning off folder previews did nothing, and neither did moving all the files in Documents, Downloads, etc. to a sub folder (so they wouldn't be included in a preview).

As mentioned, it worked fine yesterday, and the only change I can think of between the last restart yesterday and this morning is that I installed Inkscape and changed my wallpaper. However, removing Inkscape did not help, and neither did changing my wallpaper to one of the defaults.

**Update** The mystery grows: If I set it to show ~/Desktop as a "Custom location" instead, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and found the solution [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2083452#p2083452):

Deleting (or moving it, to keep a backup) `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` fixed the issue for me, albeit resetting the few settings that were tweaked.

There are other hits for this on the Internet, such as [this one](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=285630).

This was on Manjaro KDE after an update. The desktop was relatively laggy, and changing desktop settings hung up.

Partial output from `journalctl -f`:

```
plasmashell[5849]: file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.taskmanager/contents/ui/Task.qml:286: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
kernel: __vm_enough_memory: pid: 26995, comm: plasmashell, no enough memory for the allocation
```

Comment: Interesting. It would be great if we could figure out exactly which line/setting is causing this. I thought `[ScreenMapping] itemsOnDisabledScreens` was the most likely culprit since in my case this line was more then 600k characters long. I thought maybe the line just kept growing and growing until it broke something, but deleting just this line didn't seem to fix the problem. I suppose I could go through the file and delete one line at a time, but if anyone has a more practical idea, that'd be great.

Comment: Possibly; I'll try to check the contents of this file. Possibly relevant to this line, the system has a TV often connected and disconnected via HDMI.